# Android: Http response cookie store

Tags: android, httpresponse, httpcookie

I cant find any resource to understand how cookies are set by the Http response in Android. I am hitting a URL and reading the response like so:

```
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String entityStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                }
```

I am told that Http response will set a cookie that will be read by another service later. Is there anything that I need to do to ensure the cookie is set? How can I verify that the cookie is being set.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a client which extends [AbstractHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#getCookieStore()), such as [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) you can do the following to get the cookies after executing the request.

```
List<Cookie> cookiejar = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Comment: I understand that part. My question is that does Android OS handle cookies that come in the response header and place them in a universal cookie jar so it can retrieved later by a completely different service using domain name lookup. My problem is that my Http server communication is completely independent of the backend service that require the cookie to later communicate data back to the server.

Comment: No they aren't in an universal cookie jar. I would recommend you take the list of cookies returned from the server request and add them to the subsequent requests manually.