# java/android: read a textfile from the internet with authentification

Tags: java

i want to read a .txt file, which is hosted on the web. However, the link requires authentification(username and pw). How can i read this file in my app? Since the app is only for myself, i want to hardcode both name and pw.

Comment: Please post a sample of code you have attempted or are having trouble with. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must get a cookie from auth request. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927536/android-http-response-cookie-store)
2. Send a cookie in your file request. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133993/sending-cookie-info-in-httprequest)